# Numerical Computation of Electrostatic Field Lines

Tags: electric-fields, voltage, computational-physics

After solving for the potential $V(x,y)$ from a Laplace Equation $\nabla^2V=0$ in a closed 2D domain, I can readily compute the isopotential lines $V(x,y)=V_0$ with $V_0=0$ to $1$, and the Electric Field $E(x,y)=-\nabla V(x,y)$.

Now, I am figuring how to compute the Electric Field lines, since each of them should represent a fraction of the flow of the electric field as computed by the Gauss Law $E\cdot dS$, just as the isopotential lines are defined for a fraction of the total potential.

At this moment, I can trace lines by solving a trajectory for given specific points in the 2D domain, starting from and to the symmetry line $x=50$, but as you can see, they are not evenly distributed in the electric flow.

How should I impose a condition to compute the Electric Field Lines evenly distributed in flow?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by “electric flow “?

Comment: @BobD Clarified, the flow of the electric field as computed by the Gauss Law

Comment: Ok so you mean electric flux

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your picture is a parallel plate capacitor setup.

One issue might be the lack of symmetry in the blue electric field lines, which could be due to initial conditions (depending on boundary conditions, $x=50$ or $x=50.5$ might be the true midpoint of the domain). Another issue might simply be increasing the numerical accuracy of the field line solver. I assume you are directly solving $dx/ds=\vec{E}/|\vec{E}|$, where $\vec{E}=-\nabla V$ and $V$ has been interpolated through some method.

If you want to use a different numerical approach, recall that in two dimensions any solution of Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 V=0$ is the real part of some complex differentiable function $f(x+iy)=V(x,y)+i U(x,y)$, where $\partial_x V=\partial_y U$ and $\partial_y V=-\partial_x U$. Contours of $V$ are the equipotentials, and contours of $U$ are always orthogonal to contours of $V$. That is: contours of $U$ are the field lines. So one idea might be to solve for the function $U$ and then plot its contours.

Other than that, there are lots of algorithms for plotting field lines, so there could be lots of practical, algorithmic, and implementation specific details.

Comment: Interesting, so, how should I solve for U instead of V?

Comment: They're [harmonic conjugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate) of each-other.

Answer (score 0):

You're never going to get Gauss's law right in a 2d picture. Gauss's law for electrostatics is inherently a 3d law, which requires 2-d equipotentials.

Now, to answer your question, the way to "equally space the field lines by flow" you need to do the following:

1. Compute the electric field everywhere (or, at least, in enough places),
2. Find an iso-flux density ($\mathbf{E}\cdot\hat{n}$) surface, and
3. Space your field lines "equally" on that surface.

The purpose of doing this is that on a surface of constant flux density equally spacing the lines will making it so that the area "associated" with each line will be the same. Actually doing this construction is not something I know how to do. Maybe start with an equitpotential, and find some algorithm for perturbing the surface until all elements of it have an $\mathbf{E}\cdot\hat{n}$ that is the same as some reference point? Then you have the problem of defining "equally spaced" in such a way that it can be done on arbitrary surfaces.

More realistically, you could go Monte carlo - pick any surface (an equipotential would be ideal) then compute $\mathbf{E}\cdot\hat{n}$. Then peirce the surface with field lines at random points chosen with probability density $|\mathbf{E}\cdot\hat{n}|$. It's not guaranteed to work, but if you work with enough field lines it will probably work.